# setting thread values for waitress.thread

Tags: python, multithreading, gunicorn, waitress

I am using waitress to run my flask application with the code below:

```
from waitress import serve

if __name__ == "__main__":

    serve(application, host='0.0.0.0', port=SERVER_PORT)
```

When I just leave it like this, I can see in the console that waitress is working:

```
[test@gmail.com] /api/v1/messages_public?)
2021-07-07 19:55:43,277 - waitress.queue - add_task - WARNING - Task queue depth is 2
2021-07-07 19:55:43,379 - aa_api_data - parse_and_store_insights_from_message - INFO - Msg insert DB - type [file] date [2 years ago]   id [a037c16153d525470f03f5d65ef14a7a]
[test@gmail.com] /api/v1/messages_public?)
2021-07-07 19:55:43,809 - waitress.queue - add_task - WARNING - Task queue depth is 2
2021-07-07 19:55:43,848 - aa_api_data - parse_and_store_insights_from_message - INFO - Msg insert DB - type [file] date [2 years ago]   id [244d260340a4cd1d528e6f6014aacd27]
```

However, when I specify the thread count like this:

```
  serve(application, host='0.0.0.0', port=SERVER_PORT, threads=50)
```

I only see this output in the console with no waitress addons:

```
[test@gmail.com] /api/v1/messages_public?)
[test@gmail.com] /api/v1/messages_public?)
[test@gmail.com] /api/v1/messages_public?)
[test@gmail.com] /api/v1/messages_public?)
[test@gmail.com] /api/v1/messages_public?)
[test@gmail.com] /api/v1/messages_public?)
```

It also does not seem to be going much faster. Am I doing something wrong? I just want to speed up the processes on my machine when running this py script.

Comment: Can you please give more information about your code?

A simple example that reproduces the problem, because, on my PC, the following code works fine:

```python
from flask import Flask
from waitress import serve
import threading

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return f"<p>Hello, World! {threading.current_thread().name}</p>"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    serve(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, threads=10000)
```

Comment: `thread` is not for running faster for single user but for responding for more users at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You would not be able to change any thread values from the given parameters that waitress has available,
what you are doing seems to be just as much as can be done,
a possibility could be overclocking your pc if it hasnt been already though that may be a bit extreme.

https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/waitress/latest/waitress.pdf

You could find in page 11 at chapter 1.6 *waitress API*:

```py
serve(app, listen=’0.0.0.0:8080’, unix_socket=None, unix_socket_perms=’600’, threads=4,
url_scheme=’http’, url_prefix=”, ident=’waitress’, backlog=1024, recv_bytes=8192,
send_bytes=1, outbuf_overflow=104856, outbuf_high_watermark=16777216, in-
buf_overflow=52488, connection_limit=1000, cleanup_interval=30, channel_timeout=120,
log_socket_errors=True, max_request_header_size=262144, max_request_body_size=1073741824,
expose_tracebacks=False)
```